# python beautifulsoup attribute exist returns None

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

when trying to select elements that have the attribute "data-server" it returns none 
here is the code

```
>>> psoup.select_one(".server > .serverslist")
<div class="serverslist " data-server="aHR0cDovL3d3dy5jbG91ZHkuZWMvZW1iZWQucGhwP2lkPWExYWU0NjkwZmZmYjQ=">cloudy</div>
>>> psoup.select_one(".server > .serverslist[data-server]")
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup's CSS selectors are fairly limited. Attribute selectiors (`[...]`) can only be combined with a tag selector, not with other selectors (like the class selector you used):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> psoup = BeautifulSoup(
...     '<div class="server"><div class="serverslist " data-server="aHR0cDovL3d3dy5jbG91ZHkuZWMvZW1iZWQucGhwP2lkPWExYWU0NjkwZmZmYjQ=">cloudy</div></div>',
...     'lxml')
>>> psoup.select_one("div[data-server]")
<div class="serverslist " data-server="aHR0cDovL3d3dy5jbG91ZHkuZWMvZW1iZWQucGhwP2lkPWExYWU0NjkwZmZmYjQ=">cloudy</div>
>>> psoup.select_one("[data-server]")
<div class="serverslist " data-server="aHR0cDovL3d3dy5jbG91ZHkuZWMvZW1iZWQucGhwP2lkPWExYWU0NjkwZmZmYjQ=">cloudy</div>
>>> psoup.select_one(".serverslist[data-server]") is None
True
```

You'll have to find a different way of expressing your selector, one that doesn't look for attributes and classes at the same time.